# Regex Group: $1 in a string before replacement happens

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following code, which replaces a string with a part of it using `$1`:

```
my $string = "abcd1234";
print "$string\n";
    
$string =~ s/c(d1)2/<found: $1>/; 
print "$string\n";
```

Output:

```
abcd1234
ab<found: d1>34
```

---

Now I want to have variables, which contain the condition and the replacement. But if I do it like this, an error occurs:

```
my $string = "abcd1234";
print "$string\n";
    
my $cond = qr/c(d1)2/;
my $rule = "<found: $1>";
    
$string =~ s/$cond/$rule/; 
print "$string\n";
```

Output:

```
Use of uninitialized value $1 in concatenation (.) or string
abcd1234
ab<found: >34
```

I get, that `$1` isn't existing in the line, where `$rule` is defined. But how can put a placeholder there?

Answer (score 4):

You can't delay the interpretation of a variable within a quoted string like that.  `$1` is substituted as soon as the line is executed.

To do what you seem to want, you would create a `sprintf` template and execute it in the replacement part of the substitution with the `/e` flag.

```perl
my $string = "abcd1234";
print "$string\n";

my $cond = qr/c(d1)2/;
my $replacement_fmt= "<found: %s>";

$string =~ s/$cond/sprintf($replacement_fmt, $1)/e; 
print "$string\n";

## ab<found: d1>34
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sub_modify` from [`String::Substitution`](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Substitution):

```
use String::Substitution qw(sub_modify);

my $string = "abcd1234";
print "$string\n";
    
my $cond = qr/c(d1)2/;
my $rule = '<found: $1>';   # Single quotes!
    
sub_modify($string, $cond, $rule);
print "$string\n";
```

---

For completeness, note that it's also possible to do this using `s///` with the `/ee` modifier. However, you shouldn't use it, as it can lead to security issues and various bugs.